# Isolate Python methods from code snippets

Tags: python

I have a list of code snippets (not code lines but parts of lines) that I need to split up as individual strings, with any and all of their contents removed.

I'll give an example. If I have a line like this:

```
method.functionName(foo.bar(type(pm.someVariable)))
```

in a file with imports that can be a variety of different type like:

```
import reallyLongFileModuleNameThatIsWrittenPoorly as method
from filename import someVariable
from rightyOh import *  # includes foo.bar static-method, as for this example
import polymaterial as pm
```

and I would like the script to run and this to come out:

```
["method.functionName()", "foo.bar()", "pm.someVariable", "type()"]
```

- Methods that require args get (). variables (global or otherwise) don't
- Notice, type is included because it's built-in, even though it's not in the imports

Ultimately, I'd like the functionality where I can run this script from the command-line, give it a full filepath and the script will read its contents, along with whatever file(s) that it imports. From there, it should be flexible and support most if not all Python's import syntax. It'll read the file's information and, find instances of methods/class instances/etc in the code-snippets that I provide, if any.

recursive imports are NOT required for this and I'll likely provide my own PYTHONPATH to search for modules.

I get the feeling that this has been done before. Any ideas? If there aren't, I'll probably write my own using Python's inspect module but I'm thinking that modules that use import * might get a bit tricky. I'd love to know what all of you think, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how the imports have anything to do with this. It doesn't seem like you need to look at the imports to perform the analysis you want.

Comment: That's fair. The only reason why I'm focusing on imports is because it would help determine what part of code is meaningful to me and what is not. I can also use it to customize my return results with additional args, by excluding/including info based on rules. Could you please suggest how else I could achieve this?